# Fetching dynamic values from website

Tags: php, dynamic, google-ads-api, google-tag-manager

I am trying to implement dynamic re-marketing for an eCommerce website. I made all the editions in the code to call dynamic values, but still this code doesn't seem to work. I am getting an error "We haven't detected custom parameters for Retail (Google Analytics)" in AdWords.

This is the code-

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var google_tag_params = {
ecomm_prodid: '<?php echo get_the_title();?>',
ecomm_pagetype: '<?php 
if(is_page()){
   echo get_the_title()." page"; 
}else{
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['page_type'];

}
?>',
ecomm_totalvalue: '<?php $product = new WC_Product( get_the_ID() );
session_start();
if($_SESSION['page_type']=="Product details page"){
    echo $price = $product->price;
}
session_unset();
session_destroy();

?>',

dynx_itemid: '<?php echo get_the_title();?>',
dynx_pagetype: <?php 
if(is_page()){
   echo get_the_title()." page"; 
}else{
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['page_type'];

}
?>,
dynx_totalvalue: <?php $product = new WC_Product( get_the_ID() );
session_start();
if($_SESSION['page_type']=="Product details page"){
    echo $price = $product->price;
}
session_unset();
session_destroy();

?>,
};
</script>
```

Comment: It would be more useful to see how this looks after the PHP code has been parsed by the server.

Comment: Thanks @EikePierstorff, this is how it looks when this php code is parsed by the server - [ ga('set','dimension1', '10' ); 
        ga('set','dimension2', '' );
        ga('set','dimension3', '' ); ]. here dimension1, 2,3 are prodid, pagetype & totalvalue respectively.

Answer (score 0):

It's kinda hard to see what's going on (an example of the HTML output of your PHP script would be helpful), but I noticed that you don't seem to set `ecomm_pagetype` to one of the [allowable values](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/3103357?hl=en&ref_topic=3180758#retail_tag) for a retail site, namely one of `home, searchresults, category, product, cart, purchase, other`.

Also, `ecomm_prodid` needs to correspond exactly to the product's ID in your Google Merchant feed.

Comment: ga('create', 'UA-----------', 'auto');
        ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
        ga('set','dimension1', '7844' ); 
        ga('set','dimension2', 'Product details page' );
        ga('set','dimension3', '59.00' );

        ga('send', 'pageview');  

This is how my ecomm_prodid, ecomm_pagetype, ecomm_totalvalue is passed. Since including these values doesn't seem to work with re-marketing code, I have passed these values directly in google analytic tracking code and after this change server is passing values to analytic.

Comment: I'm confused, what you are describing seems to be related to Google Analytics, but Dynamic Remarketing is an Adwords feature. That's why I wrote that the complete HTML output of your script would be helpful, because I don't see any Google Analytics related there.